# Name integers in a loop

Tags: c++

I need to give these integers names like `ex_number_1`, `ex_number_2`, `ex_number_3`, etc... These are each going to be saved as a different branch of a tree. So I have done:

```
char m_variable2 [40];
For (……){

sprintf(m_variable2, "ex_number_%d",iSyst);
int m_variable2 = …

}
```

This is within another couple of loops, e.g. to vary `iSyst`. It complains about conflicting variable declarations, how do I give the integers the names of `m_variable2`?

I'm trying to copy what's already been done in huge chunks of the code for histograms, which are in this same loop and accept the following syntax:

```
hist (TString("example_"+x.at(iSyst)).Data() )->Fill (jets->at(jets.first)->phi(), weight );
```

But replacing `hist` with `int` does not work, and I have to use assignment not this `Fill` method.

Comment: you may want some sort of array instead

Comment: You'll need to provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: That won't give you a variable named `ex_number_1` or others like that - it will give you a string containing the value `ex_number_1`. C++ does not allow creating dynamically named variables. You're looking for an array, which you can access like `ex_number[1]`.

Comment: Are you looking for an associative container like [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?  e.g. `std::map<std::string, int> numbers; numbers["ex_number_1"] = 42;`

Comment: We can tell you what you're doing wrong, but to tell you how you should fix it we need a lot more information.

Comment: @0x5453 yes!! That is very close to what I need! In the square brackets can I replace the "... " with numbers [m_variable_2] so I can keep the assignment within the loop?

Comment: You could use `std::map<std::string,int>` for this. Where the std::string is the name and the int is its integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want an associative container such as [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

```
std::map<std::string, int> numbers;
numbers["ex_number_1"] = 42;

// or with a dynamic key:

std::map<std::string, int> numbers;
for (...) {
    int iSyst = ...;
    numbers[std::format("ex_number_{}", iSyst)] = 69;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It complains about conflicting variable declarations

Simply give the array variable a different name than what you gave for the integer variable. Example:

```
char m_variable2_array [40];
…
int m_variable2 = …
```

> But then the integers won't be called ex_number_1, right?

You can name the integers like that by doing this:

```
int ex_number_1 = …
```

Comment: But then the integers won't be called ex_number_1, right? I'd access them like m_variable2[...], which I'm not sure will work later on. I want them to have different names if possible. I'm copying what's already been done in the code for histograms, but what worked for them doesn't seem to work for integers

Comment: Sure, but that's going to take me a very long time manually. I went up to three as an example of the syntax I want but would need to go much higher in the actual code

Comment: @user13948 If it takes a very long time, then have you considered trying to do something else that doesn't take a long time?

Comment: The loop was my attempt at that. Sorry, I'm trying to bootstrap up based on what's already in this code, but it's becoming very clear I don't have the knowledge to do it, and that the question was poorly thought out.